# How to reconnect data-aware components (nav, grid) after "Query execution was interrupted" sql error

Tags: delphi, c++builder

when "query execution was interrupted" sql error occured, all data-aware components (TDBGrid, TDBNavigator) gets disconnected or disabled.
I've tried the dataset methods DisableControls() and EnabledControls() between query does not re-enable data-aware components.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything really, apart from turn Connected off then on on whatever DBConnection you are using, then call `Open` on your dataset.

Comment: Thanks MartynA, its me again :), when error appears, the data-aware  components gets disabled then after firedac auto re-connected, the dataset query doesn't error anymore via Close() and Open() but the data-aware components remains not working, no data rows in grid and cant add edit via TDBNav controls.

Comment: Which DB-access components are you using?  Delphi version?

Comment: MySQL local, TFDQuery dataset, TDataSource linked to TDBGrid and TDBNavigation, c++ builder

Comment: And what is it, do you think, which causes the "execution was interrupted" error?  Does it happen if you execute the query in the MySql workbench?

Comment: this happens random in app runtime in different dataset query, it always caught me off-guard. when i try to intentionally replicate the error, its not happening. im suspecting mysql service version or mysql variables now.

Comment: It's *very* unusual to having connection errors and similar when the server is on the same machine as the Delphi client app.  Frankly, it would probably be easiest for your app to run a new instance of itself when the error occurs and then shut down.